# Create dynamic array with very large size

Tags: c++, out-of-memory, dynamic-memory-allocation

I create an array as below (row =2649429, col = 17770, the size of array is 47,080,353,330 ~ 47 billions)

```
double* a= new double [row*col];
```

the error as below

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
```

The train data is around 3GB.

Please tell me how to to with the array? solution for this. 
Thanks.

Comment: What the deuce are you going to put into this array? Is every element populated?

Comment: How much ram do you have?  How much is available when you start the program?

Comment: By the size of the array, this is for https://www.kaggle.com/jieyima/netflix-recommendation-collaborative-filtering

Comment: Do some research about *sparse arrays*, or *memory mapping* together with using *windows* into the "array".

Comment: On my platform (and probably on yours as well, where sizeof(double)=8), this array takes more than GBytes. Probably doesn't worth it to hold all of it in RAM.

Comment: You’re off by two orders of magnitude. [This array needs 350 GiB](https://www.google.com/search?q=2649429+*+17770+*+64+bit+in+GiB), not 3 GiB.

Comment: The value of `row*col` gives a result that requires (at least) a 35-bit integral type to avoid overflow.  Practically, this means either `row` or `col` must be a 64-bit type to do the calculation correctly (i.e. not being truncated if the result is unsigned, and not giving undefined behaviour if the result is signed).   It also means, at minimum, free memory of (well) over 350GB, and a 64-bit operating system to address that amount of memory to allocate without error.   350GB (to say the least) exceeds what even a lot of high end computer systems have

Comment: If it's for the Netflix competition: "_The grand prize was $1,000,000 and was won by BellKor's Pragmatic Chaos team._"

Comment: Stop everything and answer a simple question -- is your application 32-bit or 64-bit?  If it's 32-bit, then this is not going to work.

Comment: 64 bit. I think it is a sparse matrix. I try to use it as an array.

Comment: I think I will using map for this. map<int, double> X
int is i*col+j
double is the value of rating. 
What do you think about this.

Comment: @ph0123 That’s a reasonable strategy if your `int`s are 64 bit. Alternatively, use `std::pair<int, int>` as the key and don’t bother about computing the offsets yourself.

Comment: It means that always the majority (eg. over 95%) of your array elements are supposed to be set to a specific value (say 0 or 1 or PI...); Hence you'll avoid allocations for elements with that specific popular value.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming this is for https://www.kaggle.com/jieyima/netflix-recommendation-collaborative-filtering by the size of the array.

You need to use a sparse array of some kind. For example, a vector of list, where you list the movies each customer has seen.

That, or you train in batches, reading small part of the data at a time.

A flat array as you suggested would be filled with mostly 0. This is way too inefficient. It only make sense if on average every customer had seen half the movies.

And using *double* is a really bad idea, anyway. Rating from 1 to 5 would fit in a char, or less, saving much data.

Lastly, notice:

> CustomerIDs range from 1 to 2649429, with gaps. There are 480189
>   users.

You should still use a sparse structure. But even if you went flat, you should then *only* have 480189 rows, not 2649429.